# How can I summarize a numeric property in a Map object?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a products variable of Map type and I need to calculate the total price of the products.

Here is the products variable:

```
Map<String, List<Product>> products
```

And the Product is defined like this:

```
class Product{
    string name;
    double price;
}
```

Here what I tried:

```
int sum = products.values().stream()
        .reduce(0, x -> x.stream().mapToDouble(y -> y.getPrice()).sum());
```

But on the row above I get this error:

> Bad return type in lambda expression: double cannot be converted to List

How can I calculate the total price of the products?

Comment: `products.values() ` is a Set<List<Product>>`.

Comment: Well, you could just use two loops. I'm assuming you don't want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to summarize all prices of all products, I think the better solution would be:

```
double sum = products.values().stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .mapToDouble(Product::getPrice)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum it like it is right now with the Map<String,List> then you could use this one:

```java
int sum = (int)products.values().stream().mapToDouble(list->list.stream().mapToDouble(Product::getPrice).sum()).sum();
```

I think you forgot that in products, .values are not the objects. Instead they are lists of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will help and is a little simpler:

```java
        int sum = (int) products.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(stream-> stream.stream())
                .mapToDouble(product -> product.price)
                .sum();
```

First, stream() will give you a stream of List<Product>, so you need to use flatMap to extract Product objects, map this products to double Stream, and call sum().